# Upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade, sql-server-2008r2-express

When I tried upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, it passed all tests and then it failed at step "Select features", saying the following error:

> There are no features selected for upgrade.

And a window error message:

> There are validation errors on this page. Click ok to close this dialog box. Review errors at the button of the setup page, then provide valid parameters or click help for more information.

Is it possible to proceed or do I need to backup, uninstall Express and then install fresh Enterprise edition?

Comment: I'm gathering this is an inplace upgrade - you're attempting to install Enterprise over top of the existing Express instance?  Might have an easier time installing Enterprise, migrate your databases & delete/remove the Express edition once the migration is done...

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I just wanted to check before doing that, as an upgrade might be an easier option, especially with all the configurations done for the Named Pipes, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point.  Still, backup/restore is painless when you know to watch for Named Pipes & protocol issues.

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I'm getting the same message...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Supported version and edition upgrade paths are listed at [Version and Edition Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx). Your upgrade path is a supported one:

```
SQL Server 2008 R2 Express  SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Tools
                            SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services
                            SQL Server 2008 R2 Workgroup
                            SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard
                            SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer
                            SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 
                            SQL Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
```

with the following note:

> This SQL Server edition can be
>   upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2 on the
>   32-bit subsystem (WOW64) of a 64-bit
>   server. Failover Clusters are not
>   supported in the WOW mode. If you
>   currently have SQL Server 2000, or SQL
>   Server 2005 failover clusters on the
>   32-bit subsystem (WOW64) upgrade of
>   the failover cluster to SQL Server
>   2008 R2 is not supported.

Is your Express edition a 32-bit install and are you trying to upgrade it to 64-bit Enterprise?

Comment: I have 64-bit Express AND 64-bit Enterprise.

Answer (score 21):

You can run Setup then select Maintenance and Edition Upgrade from that page.  From there it seems to be pretty smooth.

Comment: This was the answer I needed.  After going through Maintenance/Edition Upgrade to upgrade from Express to Enterprise, I could then go back to Installation/'New installation or add features' to add the features I was looking for (integration services and "complete" management tools).

Answer (score 1):

In our case I was upgrading a SQL Server 2008 R2 evaluation 64b to Enterprise 64b. I was getting the same error after following the upgrade steps through the GUI (not from the prompt). After I stopped all services and run the setup.exe as an administrator I was able to upgrade with no problems and it took 1 min max.

Panos.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the upgrade from a command prompt using:

```
start /wait C:\setup.exe ADDLOCAL=SQL_Engine INSTANCENAME=NameOfServerInstance UPGRADE=SQL_Engine SKUUPGRADE=1 /qb
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you run your setup program from? There are 2 programs for SQL server 2008 Installation Center available for me to run from in my SQL Server 2008 Express installation - I chose SQL Server Installation Center (64-bit) from the one under "R2" folder and it worked.